# Connector with low-cost crimper for DIY Projects

Tags: pcb-design, connector

I have a few PCBs I designed for personal DIY projects. I have been mainly using Sub-D connectors to connect them, but would love to switch to something like a DF11. However the crimpers for DF11's are very expensive. I was wondering if there is a cheaper alternative for signal connectors.

Comment: Some crimp pins can be soldered if you are very careful. After stripping the wire, carefully bend the outer metal prongs around the insulation and solder just below that. This is what I do, it is very time consuming, but for a home project it is worthwhile.

Answer (score 2):

There are certain types of crimp that, due to how common they are, you can easily find third-party crimp tools that cost quite a lot less than the manufacturer's official ones. The crimps they make may not be quite as good, and certainly won't meet the manufacturer's recommendations (which invariably include using a specific crimp tool they sell for far too much money), but they'll definitely be good enough for hobby projects. I can think of four off the top of my head.

The first are "open barrel", also called "f type", crimp terminals, which look like this:

[image: An assortment of open-barrel crimp terminals. Each one of them has two sets of "wings" folded up in a U-shape where the wire is inserted. The crimp tool will fold the wings down, one set onto the conductor and one set onto the insulation (for mechanical support).]
([image source](https://iwiss.com/how-to-crimp-open-barrel-terminals/))

And when crimped, they look like this:

[image: Three of the above terminals, crimped onto wires.]
(same source as above)

Crimp tool jaws for these look something like this:

[image: The jaws of a crimping tool, for three different sizes of open-barrel crimp. Each one has a slightly cupped bottom, and a m-shaped top, which pushes the two wings inward and down onto the wire.]
([image source](https://www.ecstuning.com/b-s-and-g-tool-aid-parts/open-barrel-crimping-tool/sgt18600%7Esgt/), though note I am not endorsing the product sold on this page; I've never used it.)

Good ones will have two sections to the crimp die for the two separate parts of the open-barrel crimp (which are slightly different sizes, as one is meant to grip the larger-diameter insulation), but you can always just use two separate crimps for them.

---

The second type are "insulated" crimp terminals, which as the name implies are insulated. These are very common, and look like this:

[image: Assorted insulated crimp terminals. They have a cylindrical plastic sheath over a (hidden) cylindrical metal part.]
([image source](https://www.aliexpress.us/item/2251832619783536.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2usa4itemAdapt&_randl_shipto=US))

These are helpfully color-coded for what size of wire they're meant to be used for; red, blue, and yellow are the most common sizes, for 22-18 AWG, 16-14 AWG, and 12-10 AWG respectively. Yellow is also used for 26-22 AWG, but these are so small that there's no risk of confusing them with the larger yellow size. Likewise, there's an even larger red size, for 8 AWG wires.

When crimped, they don't change in appearance much other than just being crushed, though some crimp tools will also stamp a mark into the plastic indicating what crimp size was used (to make it obvious whether the right size die was used). A crimp die for these typically looks something like this:

[image: A crimp die with four oval-shaped openings in different sizes, each with a colored dot above it and some numbers below it.]
([image source](https://www.tritekelectronics.com/tools/crimpers/wire-terminal-crimpers/pro-skit-cp-372fd27); again, not an endorsement of the product)

The colored dots, of course, match the color of the connectors each opening is meant to crimp.

---

Third are "closed barrel" (also "noninsulated", "uninsulated", "butted seam", or "brazed seam") connectors. These are essentially the same as the insulated terminals, minus the insulation. They look like this:

[image: A pair of ring terminals with a closed-barrel crimp. The back end of the metal is bent up into a cylinder.]
([image source](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/ring-terminals/0433028)

Crimping these simply consists of crushing them down onto the wire. The cheapest sort of crimp die for these is a half-circle on one side, and a smaller half-circle on the other that dents in the metal to lock it onto the wire.

[image: The jaws of a crimper for uninsulated terminals. They look as described above.]
([image source](https://www.cablecraft.co.uk/crt-1-5-10-crimping-tool-for-uninsulated-crimp-terminals-1-5-10mm), which still isn't an endorsement. Retailers tend to have the easiest to find images is all.)

---

The final common type of crimp connector is the coaxial connector. These are ubiquitous wherever coaxial cables are used, and as such, common cable and connector types have common crimping tools. These, of course, are of more limited use. They aren't meant for use with standard wires, but with coaxial cables, and they don't come in a wide assortment of sizes but only the sizes of standard coaxial cables. Here, for instance, is a crimp-on BNC connector for RG-58 cables:

[image: A three-piece BNC connector, with connector body, center contact, and cylindrical shield contact.]
([image source](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/amphenol-rf/112116/1011677))

This is crimped onto the cable in a multi-step process; the cable is first stripped to specified dimensions (the datasheet or engineering drawing for the connector will tell you what dimensions to use), then the center terminal is crimped onto the center contact of the cable with a diamond or hexagonal crimp die, the center contact is inserted into the body, with the shield braid spread out over the backside of the connector, then the shield contact is slid into place and crimped down with a hex crimp die. The dimensions for both crimp dice will also be given in the connector's datasheet, though there are some standard sizes for common cable types. When properly crimped, it looks like this:

[image: The two ends of a BNC to BNC cable.]
([image source](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/pomona-electronics/5697-6/737386))

The crimp die for these looks like this:

[image: A crimp die with three hexagonal holes in it, labelled as ".213", ".256", and ".068". The labels are dimensions in inches between opposite faces of the hexagons.]
([image source](https://www.specialized.net/tempo-pa2034-crimpall-die-set-rg58-and-rg59.html), though this product I actually will endorse; I've used this one and it works pretty well for the price)

The dimensions on this tool are the standard sizes for RG-58 and RG-59 crimp connectors. The center conductor for either is crimped with a 0.068" hex die, and the outer conductor is crimped with a 0.213" (for RG-58) or 0.256" (for RG-59) hex die. Just about every coaxial connector intended to be crimped onto RG-58 or RG-59 cable will use those crimp dimensions, although a fair number of them expect their center pin to be soldered instead of crimped. The outer terminal is nearly always crimped, though.

Answer (score 0):

The larger the pitch, the more likely to find an inexpensive crimper.

- 4.2 mm pitch OK? consider Molex Mini-fit connectors.
- 3.96 mm pitch, single row OK? consider single-wall Molex kk296 connectors.
- 2.54 mm pitch, single row OK? consider single-wall Molex kk100 connectors or prismatic Molex SL connectors.
- 2.54 mm pitch, two row? Amphenol Mini-PV Basics